# Why is TIDAL's default volume just 50%?

Tags: audio, default-settings, tidal

Every time I've made a fresh install of TIDAL the default volume has been set to 50%. I've a TIDAL HiFi subscription.

- Why is that?
- Is anything over 50% artificially boosting the audio?
- Is it because HiFi does sound higher than LoFi?

[image: TIDAL's volume set to 50%]

Comment: Why not ask tidal?

Comment: @Tetsujin why not make the information publicly available?

Answer (score 2):

Tidal's HiFi subscription delivers high quality audio comparable to what you get from listening to a CD. The music sounds like you're listening to one of your CDs. Tidal seems to want its HiFi subscribers to immersively experience the full quality of the music by setting the default volume conservatively to ensure that the music quality doesn't get drowned out by noise. Optional over-amplification allows raising the volume above 100% in some operating systems. This can result in a loss of audio quality. It is better to increase application volume settings if possible.

Boosting the volume over 50% does not automatically reduce audio quality, but if it does be aware that to fully appreciate what Tidal has to offer you should at least consider connecting your computer speakers to an external amplifier or DAC/amp or replacing your computer's speakers with computer speakers that have a built-in amplifier, which allows the user to control the volume using an infrared remote control. Tidal recommends to its users who listen to music with headphones to listen with good quality headphones in order to appreciate the full quality of the music.